# How to check a jlabel array is full?

Tags: java, arrays, label, jlabel

This one shows the validation popup if any of the labels are full. I want to change it so that it only shows the error message if all of the jlabels are full.

```
//check to see if car park is full
void checkFull()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < parkingSpace.length; i++)
    {

        if (parkingSpace[i].getIcon() != null)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry the Car Park is full!");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to reverse the logic of the loop. If you find an empty space, then there's no problem (return). At the end of the loop, if you haven't returned, you have no spaces left

```
//check to see if car park is full
void checkFull()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < parkingSpace.length; i++)
    {

        if (parkingSpace[i].getIcon() == null)
        {
          return;
        }

    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry the Car Park is full!");

}
```